# SQL sum of row by modified date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have an auction site and I am trying to create a simple "Total bids currently on the site" PHP page.

In my SQL database I have:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| AuctionID | InitialBid  | BidPrice   | Modified            |
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 190       | 10.00       | 10.00      | 2014-01-23 16:33:19 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 190       | 15.00       | 15.00      | 2014-01-23 16:33:35 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 191       | 10.00       | 10.00      | 2014-01-23 17:51:55 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 191       | 15.00       | 15.00      | 2014-01-23 17:52:17 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I just want the total of the highest bid prices with the newest modified date. The total should add up to 30.

I tried this but it gives me a total of 50 and just adds up everything from BidPrice. I am not sure how to make it select the newest modified price to give me the correct total of 30:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(bid_price) FROM sto8v_bid_log"; 
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result); 
echo "Total Bids Currently $ " . $row[0];
```

---

Here is my new PHP code I have been trying from user Tin Tran; it works in SQL Fiddle but not on my site.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

SELECT SUM(bid_price) AS Total
FROM sto8v_bid_log T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT auction_id,MAX(modified) AS maxmodified
FROM sto8v_bid_log
GROUP BY auction_id)T2
ON T1.auction_id = T2.auction_id
AND T1.modified = T2.maxmodified

?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home3/account/public_html/grandtotal.php on line 6
```

This is my db table with correct column names:

```
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| auction_id | userid | initial_bid | bid_price | modified            |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 190        | 770    | 10.00       | 10.00     | 2014-01-23 16:33:19 |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 190        | 771    | 15.00       | 15.00     | 2014-01-23 16:33:35 |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 191        | 753    | 10.00       | 10.00     | 2014-01-23 17:51:55 |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 191        | 771    | 15.00       | 15.00     | 2014-01-23 17:52:17 |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Bid_Price) as Total
FROM sto8v_bid_log T1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT AuctionId,MAX(Modified) as MaxModified
    FROM sto8v_bid_log
    GROUP BY AuctionId)T2 
ON T1.AuctionId = T2.AuctionId
AND T1.Modified = T2.MaxModified
```

You'll have to get MAX(Modified) for each AuctionId then JOIN that back with your table to get the Bid_Price and then SUM() it.

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b41e/5/0)

php code below

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","login","pass","database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($link))
    {
        echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(bid_price) AS total
                FROM sto8v_bid_log T1
                INNER JOIN
                (SELECT auction_id,MAX(modified) AS maxmodified
                FROM sto8v_bid_log
                GROUP BY auction_id)T2
                ON T1.auction_id = T2.auction_id
                AND T1.modified = T2.maxmodified";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql); //this line executes query

    // error checking
    if (!$result){
        printf("Error: %s\n%s\n", mysqli_sqlstate($link),mysqli_error($link));
    }

    // 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "Total Bids Currently $ " . $row['total'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work. i see it works correct in sqlFiddle.  i have edit my post to show my php and the error i getting. if you have any idea why i would get that error i would love some help.  Thank you.

Comment: you have to set your $sql = that SQL then execute it like you did before you can't just paste SQL into the middle of PHP and expect it work right?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I am new to SQL and php so this is all new to me, i been trying to learn it as i go. I dont know what commands to use in php to execute the sql . thank you

Comment: I am learning PHP too. but you can search for `PHP mysqli query` there are lots of examples.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include some sample PHP code try that and see if it works, you might have to change the hostname,username,password,database details.

Comment: You are my HERO !!! that worked perfect.  if i could buy you a beer i would.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the maximum price per auction id,  group it by each auction and also by modified.

```
select AuctionID, max(BidPrice), Modified FROM sto8v_bid_log GROUP BY 1, 2
```

The need of a sumarized value of 30 is not possible due to the fact that you are requesting clearly to report: foreach auction,  the maximum price offered or payed and the date time when it was offered/payed.